# what performance metrics is more important to comapre classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, model-evaluation, supervised-learning

I have classified my biological data by using a few machine learning algorithms and calculated sensitivity, specificity, AUC, accuracy, kappa, PPV and NPV etc.? which one of these metrics are the most important when I want to select the "best" performing model?

Comment: You may be interested in a question I just posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/proper-scoring-rule-when-there-is-a-decision-to-make-e-g-spam-vs-ham-email.

Comment: Best for what purpose? What are the costs for different kinds of errors?

Comment: We can't tell you, you have to tell us. That is, which one is best depends on the particular case.